# Manipular DataFrame pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tenho esse dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

dados = [['Empresax', 'AC', '803.5', ''],
            ['Empresay', 'AC', '776.6', ''],
            ['Empresaxy', 'AC', '', ''],
            ['Empresaxyx', 'PA', '8.1', ''],
            ['Empresa xyxy', 'RO', '1.7', ''],
            ['Empresa z', 'RR', '505.6', ''],
            ['Empresa zx', 'RR','' , '']]

df = pd.DataFrame(dados, columns=['EMPRESA', 'CHAVE', 'VALOR', 'VALOR_TOTAL'])
```

Preciso fazer um filtro com as `'CHAVES' = 'AC'` e fazer a soma para incluir na coluna Valor_total. O mesmo valor total ficara na Empresax, Empresay e na Empresaxy por pertencerem a mesma chave, ou seja, vou poder saber quanto as Empresas juntas daquela Chave geraram para depois poder continuar manipulando meu DataFrame.

Comment: Samuel, consegue verificar se minha resposta atende a sua pergunta?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma variável para selecionar apenas as linhas que atendem o filtro e com `loc` selecionar as linhas do df que você quer tanto atualizar como somar os valores da coluna **VALOR**

```
df['VALOR'] = pd.to_numeric(df['VALOR'])

g = df['CHAVE'] == 'AC'
df.loc[g, 'VALOR_TOTAL'] = df.loc[g, 'VALOR'].sum()
df.head()
#saida:

    EMPRESA       CHAVE VALOR   VALOR_TOTAL
0   Empresax        AC  803.5   1580.1
1   Empresay        AC  776.6   1580.1
2   Empresaxy       AC  NaN     1580.1
3   Empresaxyx      PA  8.1 
4   Empresa xyxy    RO  1.7 
5   Empresa z       RR  505.6   
6   Empresa zx      RR  NaN
```

Comment: Deu certo. obrigado

Comment: @SamuelMesquita se você puder aceitar ela então, clicando no "V" ali na esquerda eu agradeço :)